# How can I get the name of the user that added a user to a group that I own using facebook graph or explorer?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well, I can get the list of the members that I have on my group, but how can I see who added them ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the docs, there is only the information if the user is an administrator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/members

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for some tricks or ideas to get this kind of informations, I mean clearly facebook can know who added X user & when, but in the explorer there is no information about these 2 attributes

Comment: not everything that is visible on facebook.com is available with the api.